# Having trouble understanding where to store private keys

Tags: api, security, cryptography

I am having an issue determining how to store API keys or other private information correctly. I have a helper library for a large set of inner-facing company applications that calls an external API for emailing and must have access to the API key. I store this key in a shared configuration file used by these applications. If I wanted to further secure the key by encrypting it or moving it to a service like Azure Key Vault, I then am stuck with the dilemma of having simply complicated the problem because I now have the private key for that encryption or the key to access Azure Key Vault that I now need to secure. Because this type of issue is so common I am assuming I am missing something here. Each time I try to further encrypt or otherwise secure a key I am simply adding another layer of the same problem. I still end up with a private key sitting somewhere in plain text. Is it the case that having a plain text key in an otherwise secure environment is just not an issue after all?

I would like to point out that I cannot use Environment Variables or some of the other tools I have seen to secure keys on the machine as these applications can be run on any number of terminal servers or local machines throughout the company. Most are click-once Dot Net applications written in .Net 4.5 and can run anywhere in our environment, some by any user in our domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use azure but I assume Azure Key Vault is very similar to [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) which is exactly the thing I would use (I wrote about one use [case for storing Amplitude API keys on my blog](https://curiousprogrammer.net/posts/2022-02-16-aws-secrets-manager-least-privilege)).

Why is this better than simply having the key lying around in a file?

- Simplified key distribution: you don't need to download the key on all the machines
- Improved security: you simply load the key at runtime, no need to have the key lying on the disk forever

Note there's not much point in double-encrypting the key as you mentioned. That's just increasing complexity without improving the security of the solution much.
Also, in case of AWS, you would specify a very granular IAM policy/permissions for accessing the specific secret and attach the policy to the IAM role assigned to the instances needing to work with the key.

Comment: tbh I am having an issue of scale. I have over 60 legacy apps that would need to be registered with Azure in this case. They are currently sending SMTP emails via a library but are swapping to SendGrid API and I am trying to secure the SendGrid API key. I could provide an intermediary API for sending emails so even if we move on from SendGrid these legacy apps don't need updated but I then run into the issue of having that API's key needing to be present in all of those apps if I want to secure the intermediary API. Should I give in and register all these apps to use a more secure standard?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What "more secure standard" are you talking about? For sure, you can store the SendGrid API key in the Vault but of course you need to modify the apps to load the key from the Vault.

Comment: Essentially just want you indicate, modifying each application to connect to the key vault without the need to store a key string somewhere. Your answer put me on the path to understand what I was so confused about. I was under the mistaken impression that they key vault would provide me a key to access the vault thereby putting me back in the same position I was originally in. Digging further into what you said above it seems I am offloading the work to two trusted systems, locally and the vault, to exchange temporary tokens for me to access the key in the vault. Thanks for the answer.